# How to access elements of Firebase Snapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that looks like this:

```
masterSheet
    0
        0: 0
        1: "What is your favorite type of dog?"
        2: "Some values"
        3: "Some more values"
        4: "Blah blah"
        5: "Animals"
    1
        0: 1
        1: "What's 2 + 2?"
```

I'm using this code to retrieve a snapshot of the databse.

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('masterSheet')

ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var data = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

This seems to work, as when I run it in a browser and do inspect element > console, I can see:

```
(6) [0, "What is your favorite type of dog?", "Some values", etc
(6) [1, "What's 2 + 2?", "Some values", etc
```

The problem is that I can't seem to access this data like a normal JavaScript object. I'm using this for a web app quiz, and need to be able to access each question individually and the associated values.

If I try to access the first value in the object with console.log(data[0]), this is the result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
etc
```

Which seems right, but if I do data[1], the result is "undefined."

What am I doing wrong here? Basically I need to make a list of dictionary objects, or a nested dictionary, or something where I can access each question by calling the index/number associated with it.  I would like to be able to make an object where the keys are the question numbers (0-indexed) and then the rest of the values are in nested dictionaries within that object.

But for the last couple days I've been trying to figure out how to access this Firebase snapshot and just can't figure out the structure.

Edit: Here is the structure of my JSON.

```
{
  "masterSheet" : [ [ 0, "What's 2+2?", "22", "4", "6", "Math question" ], [ 1, "What's the capital of Nevada?", "Reno", "Las Vegas", "Carson City", "Geography" ], [ 2, "What's the meaning of life?", "40", "41", "42", "Philosophy" ] ]
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: This seems to work fine for me: https://jsbin.com/pehiyos/3/edit?js,console
Can you clone that link, and reproduce the problem within there?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm getting. I see in the console the entire object, the problem is I can't figure out how to access it.

Comment: Edit: Never mind I don't know what happened but now I'm able to access the values with data[1], data[2], etc. Not sure what I was doing wrong before but it works. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear. I voted to close your question as not reproducible. I recommend creating a reproduction like the one I posted in the future to make it more likely we can help.